# infinitly execution while send broadcast

Tags: android

I want to use
`context.sendBroadcast(intent, receiverPermission);`

in my application
but I don't know to pass receiverPermission parameter in function and also how to set in manifest file
please any body help me

I want to show you my source code

```
public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "LOCATION_CHANGE";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        intent.setAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        Location loc = (Location)b.get(android.location.LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
        Logger.debug("Loc:"+loc);
        if(loc != null){
            doBroadCast(context,intent,loc);
        }
    }

    public void doBroadCast(final Context context,final Intent i1,final Location loc){
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Logger.debug("LocationReceiver->sendLocation update broadcast");
                i1.putExtra("Latitude", loc.getLatitude());
                i1.putExtra("Longitude", loc.getLongitude());
                context.sendBroadcast(i1,null);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and on activity I have write

```
  @Override

        protected void onResume() {
            registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(LocationReceiver.BROADCAST_ACTION));
}

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                UpdateUI(intent);
            }
        };

        private void UpdateUI(Intent i){
            Double Latitude = i.getDoubleExtra("Latitude",0); 
            Double Longitude = i.getDoubleExtra("Longitude",0);
            showMap(Latitude, Longitude);
        }
```

Now my problem is when it sendbroadcast it execute infinitly doBroadcast function(), please help me to come out.

Comment: 1. What does the code for the initiation of the first broadcast look like? 2. What Intent Filter did you set up for your LocationReceiver class in your Manifest?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check after  `intent.setAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);` that the action is really set to `BROADCAST_ACTION`
2. Check if you have registered this `BroadcastReceiver` with the action `BROADCAST_ACTION` in the `<intent-filter>` ( if it is, then that s why you have that infinite loop)